# sqlite connection with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a simple piece of code where I connect my sqliteDb.
My sqlite3_prepare_v2 though repeatedly fails. I narrowed it down to the following piece of code:

```
NSString *sqLiteDb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xyz" ofType:@"sqlite3"];
```

sqLiteDb returns null. I don't know why - tried everything I could and followed many threads.
Really struggling here - please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in.h file

```
 NSString *databasePath;


in .m file


NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,               NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
  databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbname.sqlite"];    
  [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
    {
     // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
     BOOL success;

     // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
     // of the database and to copy it over if required
     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

     // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
     success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

     // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
     if(success) return;

     // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

     // Get the path to the database in the application package
     NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]  stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

     // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
     [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your `xyz.sqlite3` file is included in the correct Target Membership? If it is not included, then it will not be copied to your bundle when building.

[image: Screenshot]